# Is there an equivalent of DataFrames 'describe' to a postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to summarize multiple tables in my database getting each columns statistics (min, max, avg, num of null values, etc.).

Is there a postgresql command/tool for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql maintains statistics on all tables. They are made visible via the [pg_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html) view.

It contains at least some of the information you are after, such as the proportion of null values, as well as other potentially useful info like histograms of most commonly occurring values, etc.

These statistics are maintained by the database itself, to aid in query planning.

Example Usage: Obtain fraction of nulls and number of distinct values in table 'foo':

```
ispdb_t1=> select tablename || '.' || attname as tablecolumn, null_frac, n_distinct  from pg_stats where tablename='foo';
    tablecolumn    |  null_frac  | n_distinct
-------------------+-------------+------------
 foo.name          |           0 |         -1
 foo.a             | 0.000785309 |          4
 foo.b             | 0.000241633 |          4
 foo.id            |           0 |         -1
 foo.d             |           0 |        553
(6 rows)
```

Comment: any idea why a specific table/scheme will not be listed under pg_stats? tried searching and couldn't find a flag to 'turn on' to enable it

Comment: Perhaps the system had not analyzed the table yet.  Try giving command `ANALYZE table` where table is the name of the table.